# How can I prevent a non-promoted instance from consuming a message

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Whenever I deploy a new version in Google App Engine, and I transfer traffic to it, the previous version still consumes messages from our message broker. How can I make sure only the newly deployed version will consume messages without shutting down the old instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple versions deployed while traffic is being migrated, you can check the current version using the [Modules API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.modules.modules) and compare that with the default version.

Your check might look something like this:

```py
from google.appengine.api import modules

def default_version = modules.get_default_version()
def instance_version = modules.get_current_version_name()

# you may additionally want to query the instances of the default version 
# to make sure they've booted up and are actively serving traffic.

if default_version != instance_version:
  # don't consume messages
```

In the code example above, the **default version** is the version traffic is being migrated to, and the **current version** is the version of the instance.

See also [Using the Modules API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/using-the-modules-api).

Note: Services were formerly known as modules and the API methods still reflect that naming.

Comment: Apparently this only works for standard environment. For flexible environment, App Engine Admin API can be used instead:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services/get

Comment: Are you on flex or standard?

Comment: I forgot to mention we are on flex. I appreciate your answer, I was looking for something like that and didn't get to it until you mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

During the deployment of your service, you can use --promote and --stop-previous-version options.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy

However, generally it's best to gradually migrate the traffic. This is the case for both users and backend services. Since you can't deploy two services at the exact same time, imagine your GAE deployment is delayed by a few seconds. Do you expect the messages to be consumed by your running service that is getting replaced? So, it shouldn't matter if a few messages still got routed to the old instance while the traffic is migrating. That would be the right design.